# Code coverage report from Istanbul for Protractor has no output

Tags: gulp, protractor, istanbul

This may be a two part question because my configuration may be a little messed up. I am trying to get a code coverage report for my protractor tests; grunt-protractor-coverage with istanbul no longer works with protractor version 3.3 so I am using gulp-istanbul with protractor-istanbul-plugin instead. I have instrumented the files I need but I cannot get protractor to use those instrumented files.

gulpfile.js:

```
var istanbul = require('gulp-istanbul');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('concat', function(){
gulp.src('coverage/*.js')
// Instrument for protractor-istanbul-plugin:
    .pipe(istanbul({coverageVariable: '__coverage__'}))
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('test/e2e/testresults'))
    .pipe(istanbul.writeReports());
});
```

So first off, the example at [Code coverage for Protractor tests in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350680/code-coverage-for-protractor-tests-in-angularjs) helped me out with building the initial stuff, but I feel as though my `gulp.src` is incorrect. Right now the `gulp.src` points to where my coverage files are. Right now, my `npm run` command is `"protractor": "gulp concat && protractor test/e2e/mockDataConf.js"` in the package.json, and when I run this command the results of the tests are output before the tests even run. I am getting `0/0 100%` across the board for everything in the report.

mockDataConf.js :

```
..//configuration stuff here...
var istanbulPlugin = require('protractor-istanbul-plugin');
plugins: [{
    inline: istanbulPlugin,
    logAssertions: true,
    failAssertions: true,
    outputPath: '../../test/e2e/testresults'
}]
```

So am I supposed to be directing the `gulp.src` to the directory with my instrumented files and why is the report output being shown before the tests run?

Edit: I now understand that this is just concat'ing the files I want to use and instrumenting them into a `script.js` file. I will update more once I get this all working.

Comment: After two weeks of trying all the modules and plugins available for protractor coverage testing, I have come to the conclusion that protractor is not a suitable platform to do coverage testing. If it is possible, it's exceptionally difficult and the amount of work required may outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Do you have any output for this now?